# Android: Want to put an silhouette overlay on a Camera preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'd like to know how I can put a silhouette on top of a camera preview. So far i've got the following example working, which just previews the Camera.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

I'm trying to have a Camera preview, where I got a silhouette shown so the person using the app gets an idea of where the picture should be taken, and then a button that when clicked, takes the picture, without the silhouette of course in the picture.

How can this be done? I can't seem to find any examples of how to put an overlay on top of a texture view.

Comment: A `TextureView` behaves just like a regular `View`, so you'd do it just like you'd put any `View` over another `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. Let's say I don't know how to do that neither :D

Comment: There are plenty of examples already here on-site, but a quick description of a possible option: create a layout XML file with a `FrameLayout` as the root `View`. List the `TextureView` as the first child of the `FrameLayout`, with its `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. List an `ImageView` as the second child with the same dimensions, make its `background` transparent - `#00000000` - and set its `src` to your silhouette image, which should also have a transparent background. Then load your layout file in the `setContentView()` call instead of just the `TextureView`.

Comment: @MikeM. I'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeM. I really can't seem to get any example to work :/

Comment: Gimme a minute. I'll post a quick example.

Comment: @MikeM. That'll be perfect!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the example in the [`TextureView` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) you've linked, we simply create a layout XML file to hold our `TextureView` and overlay `ImageView` in a `FrameLayout`. We then call the `Activity`'s `setContentView()` method with this layout's Resource ID, instead of the dynamically-created `TextureView` in the example.

The layout file, `main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView android:id="@+id/texture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the sample `Activity`:

```
public class LiveCameraActivity extends Activity
    implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    // The TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener methods
    // are the same as shown in the example.

    ...
}
```

The overlay `ImageView` in the layout uses the default launcher icon as its source image, as it has transparency, at least on my IDE. You would later replace this image with your silhouette. The `ImageView`, being listed after the `TextureView`, will appear on top of it, because `View`s are drawn with respect to their z-order in the same order they're listed in the layout, with the first `View` listed being on the bottom; i.e., the farthest away from you on the z-axis.

In the `Activity`, we're just loading the layout as the content `View`, and getting a reference to the `TextureView` created there. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Nothing short of amazing! I've tried for hours to make this work, and I feel like I've done exactly what you just wrote, several times. But this worked! Thank you so much man! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: The camera now fills the entire screen. Would you know how to make it smaller? I tried adding in stuff like:
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
            parameters.SetPictureSize(width, height);
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);

But that doesn't seem to solve it. It remains same size all the time.

Comment: Yeah, you would change the size of the `TextureView`; actually the parent `FrameLayout`. You can treat my sample layout as kind of a single `View`, and put it inside whatever other layout you want, like you would when you add a `Button` or an `EditText` to an `Activity`'s layout. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay. Sorry for asking you yet again, but I'm not very familiar with Android.

Let's say I'd like a black frame, within that I want a TextureView(The image the camera is previewing), but It has to be slightly smaller than the frame, so I can see it around the Textureview. And in the bottom of the black frame, I'd like a button to Capture the Image. How would that look like(If you got the time for that :) )

Comment: Yeah, [here ya go](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yCxiylEdYkVGc1ZFRWOHlXMjQ/view?usp=docslist_api). I still had my editor open with that layout, so it was a quick adjustment. Lemme know if you have trouble accessing that. I don't use Drive very often.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll check this tomorrow! :D